# "Say to somebody about" vs "tell somebody about"

Tags: meaning, usage

I've gone through a lot of English-learning resources and I know the difference in usage between "say" and "tell". And yet, I'm not sure if the following sentences, some of which seem related to ditransitive constructions, would be correct or acceptable.

> 1.I said to the police about what happened. 
>   2.I said to the police what happened. 
>   3.I told the police about what happened. 
>   4.I told the police what happened. 
>   5.I said to the police about it. 
>   6.I said it to the police. 
>   7.I told the police about it. 
>   8.I told it to the police.

Thank you.

Comment: I'll preface this by saying I'm not a native speaker of English. Nevertheless, even though *tell* and *say* are pretty much interchangeable, *tell*, I find, is usually used with the meaning of *inform*, whereas *say* is more literal: it introduces the actual utterance (perhaps not necessarily in its verbatim form).

Comment: This may not be a legit comment, but I want to commend @userr2684291 for a good and concise clarification on say and tell. Secondly, I want to express a meta-issue, talking to police. I have it on professional advise to _not do it_. Everything you say will be used against you.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. *I said to the police about what happened.* **Incorrect.**  (*Say* normally requires a direct object when it means pronouncing a word, expressing an opinion, or stating a fact.  It can occasionally be intransitive in some of its less common senses: see [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/say).)
> 2. *I said to the police what happened.* **Borderline.** *I said what happened* on its own would be correct, but adding the indirect object sounds awkward here.
> 3. *I told the police about what happened.* **Correct.**
> 4. *I told the police what happened.* **Correct.**
> 5. *I said to the police about it.* **Incorrect.** (Similar to *1* above.  May be acceptable to some speakers in very colloquial use.)
> 6. *I said it to the police.* **Correct**, although we would be more likely to say *I said that to the police* or *I said the same thing to the police*.  Having just the word *it* sounds a bit awkward somehow (see also *8* below).
> 7. *I told the police about it.* **Correct.**
> 8. *I told it to the police.* **Correct**, although in most cases we would be more likely just to say *I told the police* or (as above) *I told the police about it*.  Other expressions such as *I told my story to the police* and *I told the truth to the police* also sound better than *I told it to the police*.

[This](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/say-or-tell) is also worth a look.